# Dynamic Content using Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, dynamic

I am relatively new to creating apps, I noticed on some apps that there are images or content that will change with our the app having to be updated, how is this achieved? I have been looking everywhere I could think of and have came up empty.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael mentions you can use a `UIWebView` and `UIImageView` to render the contents of a particular URL. However, most dynamic content on the iPhone is achieved using web services rather than directly rendering a web page.

If you are not familiar with web services, you can think of them as a stripped-down form of content; they are the link between the database and the client. In this model, the client requests data from the web service, the web service fetches from the database, and the client renders the web service response as he sees fit.

For example, you can use a JSON-based web service to return content like `{"Movie":"Title","Review":"Pretty good"}` and create a content view with two `UILabels`, one bigger and one smaller, to reflect this:

`movieLabel.text = [[JSONParser parseString:[WebServiceClient JSONForRequest:&request] movieString];`
`reviewLabel.text = [JSONParser parseString:[WebServiceClient JSONForRequest:&request] reviewString];`

Read more about web services and iOS at http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Answer (score 1):

These are typically apps that get their resources via URL references to servers providing content (graphics, images, the latest "sale" page or whatever).

Many iOS classes (such as `NSData` or `NSString`) have initializers like [`initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL%3aencoding%3aerror%3a).  Other classes (like `UIImage`) can be easily instantiated with data downloaded from a URL ([`imageWithData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData%3a)).

You can also embed web views ([`UIWebView` objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView)) into your app and simply point that web view at some convienent URL on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Apps can request data from a remote server and download it to the app. You can use classes in URL loading system to interact with remote servers. Here is a [link] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html for further reading.